# What is the recommended way to parse dates in different formats?

Tags: java, regex, string, date, split

I'm working on an Java assignment to create a program that accepts a date in multiple formats:

Day must be `DD`, Month can be `MM` (in digits) or `MMM` (first 3 letters), and Year can be `YY` or `YYYY`. Delimiters may be slash, dot or dash.

Examples of input to be accepted:

- `1/May/2001`
- `23.8.9`
- `7-01-01`

My problem is the user input is accepted by a String. So I need to separate the information between the delimiters.

What should I use to do this? It is recommended I use the `java.util.regex` package?

Comment: Take a look at `String#split`

Comment: Please don't write `Java` in the title when `Java` is tagged.

Comment: @user2706930,   Your problem is very open ended. For a input like `01-02-03`, there is no way to be sure which one is month, day or year. It could be mm-DD-YY or YY-mm-DD. Are there any restriction in user inputs which will help identity this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create different format Strings and cycle on them parsing with `SimpleDateFormat` catching the `ParseException`. It's not an elegant solution but it should work.

You can do something like this, adjust to your needs:

```
String[] formatStrings = {"dd/MM/yyyy", "dd.mm.yy", "dd-mm-yyy"};

//...

Date tryParse(String dateString)
{
    for (String formatString : formatStrings)
    {
        try
        {
            return new SimpleDateFormat(formatString).parse(dateString);
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {
          \\you can log the error
         }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use Arrays as long as I don't know a proper collection causes performance issues. And don't return null. Return a default value or throw an exception. But appart from such minor details I'd consider the approach as elegant as it gets using Java.

Answer (score 0):

You said it yourself buddy. Use `spit` to carve up your message. The first thing you should do is check what delimiter type they use:

```
if(input.contains("/")
{
     delim = "/";
}
else if(input.contains(".")
{
     delim = ".";
     // you get the idea.
}
```

Then you simply use the `split` method to separate the string into separate strings based on that delimiter:

```
String[] tokens = input.split(delim);

// Value in tokens for input "22/12/1985"

     [0] = "22"
     [1] = "12"
     [2] = "1985"

// Value in tokens for input "009/1990"

     [0] = "009"
     [1] = "1990"
```

**Edit to include some Regex information**

You can split out the part that involves looking for the delimiter by using some simple regex.

```
String pattern = "[/|-|\.| ]";
String[] values = input.split(pattern);
```

This will search for `"/"`, `"-"`, `"."` and `" "`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a mask with class SimpleDateFormat to obtain what you want:

example:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = 
        new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment is mainly about detecting the format, not parsing it once you know which it is. A regular expression can sure help, but is not enough in itself.

My recommendation would be to first detect which delimiter is used by calling `String#indexOf`, then splitting by that delimiter, then analyzing which part means what. In this step a regex may come in handy.

### EDIT

In fact, there is no need for the *ifology* to detect the delimiter: you can split on `[\-./]`, covering any delimiter in one go.

Comment: But what to do if there is 21.8.2003 and 8.8.2003 or 8.08.2003? Than it is at a other index...

Comment: @Gerret That's immaterial. With `indexOf` you test for existence. It returns -1 if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the day, month and year as one value use split!

```
String date = "10/08/2003";
date.split("/");
```

You get a array with the values!

If you want to check if the String is a valid date, use regex. It is the best was to check if a string is valid! Use this tutorial [here](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-date-with-regular-expression/) to know how to check a date with regex.

Use contains to check wich delimiter you have to use. Because with a valid date with regex could only have it at the right place.

```
date.contains("/")
```

This method returns true if the date contains a "/". You should use that in a if condition!